# How to setup minimized change tracking in LibreOffice 4.2.x

Tags: libreoffice

If change tracking is enabled in Libreoffice 4.2.x it tracks really every action, also those that I wouldn't consider a change, whose which are withdrawn and those which `diff` wouldn't consider changes (if it would be run over the original and the changed document).

E.g. adding and removing `b` to and from `Abc` result in both removal and addition being tracked whereas one might (and `diff` would) consider this to be not a change at all.

[image: Change tracking in LibreOffice 4.2.x after removing and adding <code>b</code> to <code>Abc</code>]

I would like to set up LibreOffice to do the latter in general, i.e. track only the minimal set of changes.